# How to build a constant Graphics object

Tags: plotting, dynamic, animation

I'm making an animation with `Manipulate` for a representation. The code looks like this

```
plot1 = Plot[f[x, y] , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Manipulate[{plot0[s], Show[plot1, plot2[s]]}, {s, -1, 1}]
```

The thing is that `plot1` is a large 3D plot requiring complex calculation, but it is independent from `s`. `plot2`, which being dependent on `s`, can be calculated easily (it's just a spinning plane). I've tried

```
Manipulate[{plot0[s], Show[plot2[s]]}, {s, -1, 1}]
```

It auto-runs smoothly. But the former code did not perform so well and there were constant interruptions in the animation. So how can I tell *Mathematica* not to re-evaluate `plot1` every time `s` changes? Since I need `plot1` and `plot2` in the same Graphics, and synchronized with & juxtaposed next to `plot0`, I can't really take `plot1` out of the `Manipulate` function. Thanks!

Comment: since `plot1` is constant already (it is evaluated before even Manipulate does anything), then M does not evaluate it again. What you are seeing in the rendering of it on the screen, which is slow for large objects, not the evaluation. You can try to Rasterize plot1 and see if this improves the rendering performance.

Comment: @Nasser But I kind of need plot1 in 3D. Maybe I have to export the animation.

Comment: If you can show the plot1, may be someone can suggest some things. For example, adding `Opacity` can slow down things quite a bit (since this requires more layers), I remember there was another graphic primitive that was expensive to use but forget it now. You can btw test this yourself. Make a manipulate that only displays plot1, like this `Manipulate[x;plot1,{{x,0,"x="},0,1,.1}]` and let it run (play the slider). You can now get an idea how long it takes to render plot1 on its own each time. You'll see that the less 3D points/primitive, the faster it will run.

Comment: Would //InputForm help? Save plot1 as its input form? BTW, do you mean Plot3D instead of Plot above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My intuition is that the problem is with the front end and not the kernel.  The front end will need to render the combined 3D graphics, even if only one changes (unless GPUs have gotten so sophisticated they can manage and compose multiple 3D images -- but on my computer the CPU is heavily engaged).

#### Speedier rendering

The trick to building a speedier `Manipulate` is to have two plots, `plot1` and a simplified version, which I will call `plot1CA`.  (CA is for [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlActive.html), about which command you should read, if you do not know it already.)

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, PlotPoints -> 100];
plot1CA = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6},
  PlotPoints -> 35, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None];
```

We can estimate the time to render `plot1` and `plot1CA` as follows:

```
(* two cells -- execute both simultaneously *)
SessionTime[]
plot1     (* <-- important: no semicolon here *)

(*new cell*)
SessionTime[] - %%
(* 0.578488 <-- very slow *)
```

Similarly...

```
SessionTime[]
plot1CA

(*new cell*)
SessionTime[] - %%
(* 0.092861 <-- slow but reasonably responsive; reduce PlotPoints further, if desired *)
```

If your plot is say from `ListPlot3D[data]`, consider downsampling with something like `plot1CA = ListPlot3D[data[[;; ;; 10, ;; ;; 10]]` (and adjusting [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DataRange.html) accordingly).

#### The `Manipulate`

We can use [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlActive.html) to switch between the full plot and the simplified one.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ControlActive[plot1CA, plot1],
  Plot3D[(Cos[t] x + Sin[t] y)/6, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]
  ],
 {t, 0., 2. Pi}]
```

Since `plot1` and `plot1CA` have been pre-computed, there is no need to use `Dynamic`; they are just static data.  In fact, we need the whole to be updated, so the image to be rendered can switch between the small amount of data `plot1CA` when the control is being moved and the larger `plot1` when the control is released.

Comment: @kuba I don't understand what it does that is unnecessary.  I think the 3D graphics makes it significantly different that 2D.  I think the FE has to calculate the relationship between elements of the static `plot1` and the dynamic `plot2` every time `plot2` is updated, and the delay occurs there, not in the kernel. The kernel can reevaluate `plot1` in microseconds, so wrapping it in `Dynamic` does not save much time.  It's different with 2D graphics.  (The OP rather confusingly uses `Plot` and says it's a 3D graphic.)  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, 3D is different story.